# Sharing a module in node.js to avoid multiple includes

Tags: node.js

In Node.js, considering a main.js file:

```
const TOOLS = require('myTools.js');
const LIB1 = require('lib1.js');
const LIB2 = require('lib2.js');
```

I'll use `TOOLS` functions from the main module (main.js), from `LIB1` and from `LIB2`.

`TOOLS` will stablish connections to the database and I'm not sure if it is a good idea doing `const TOOLS = require('myTools.js');` multiple times on different modules.

How do I "share" `TOOLS` so it is visible from everywhere?

Comment: Node.js caches requires, so you can require the same module in however many places you want, without it really having any negative effect.

Comment: *docs* - [Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get exactly the same object returned](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching)

Comment: Oh no, I don't mess with Community, and I do think it's been answered before, and is a duplicate, I just don't think global variables is the correct answer.